# Laravel queue create

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Firstly, thanks in advance for any help given, I really appreciate it.

I'm at the beginning of creating a new website for a client of mine, they have the following models:

Property, Office and Team.

Each Property and Team can be assigned 1 Office.

I have the relationships set up, as well as the models and migrations etc.

The way we import these properties is via a SOAP WSDL feed, and at the moment I simply have a controller that runs through whats in the WSDL file, what's in the DB, and updates/creates Properties based on the updated_time.

My problem is that, because there could be up to 1000 properties, and the "create" process can be quite extensive (saving and cropping Property images etc), the script can take quite a long time to complete.

Is this something I could turn into a Queue/Job type situation? If so, how would I go about doing this? If not, what do?

Comment: Yes do it in queue then

Comment: How you convert this to a queue is a bit broad.  Generally speaking, execute the import code in a job class and dispatch the job from the controller.

Comment: Thanks @Devon so if I create a Job that create's a new Property with the information given to it, then dispatch to a queue. Would I have a job per Property, or a Job that handles all?

Comment: That's really up to you, but if it's all the same import, I don't see why you'd want to split them up into multiple jobs.

Answer (score 0):

definitely,

all what you have to do is to create a new class dedicated for the creation of your resource, and then when you get to the place where you need to create the resource, you push the job (the class and its parameter) to the queue.

you'd need of course to set up a queue in place, and then add a worker to consume this queue